# Updated API works locally but not on Heroku even when its using updated code

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, knex.js, heroku-postgres

I'm revisiting an old note taking project and updated the response from a post request to include the id of the new note instead of just a message with "new note created" like before. I pushed the changes to github and the heroku auto-deploy build succeeded.

My issue is that I get the proper response of `{id: 'id', message: 'message'}` when I test the api locally but heroku gives me the old response of `{message: 'message'}` like its using the older version of the api. There are no bad statuses or error messages and the build is using the newest code from git as far as I'm aware. Any idea why this is happening? I feel like I might be missing something obvious.

The updated api call looks like this:

```
server.post('/api/notes', (req, res) => {
  const note = req.body;

  knex
    .insert(note)
    .into('notes')
    .then(response => {
      res
        .status(201)
        .json({ id: response[0], message: 'New note successfully created' });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error creating note' });
    });
});
```

The old code is the same except the json response doesn't have the 'id' property.

Also just to show heroku is using the latest code:

[pic of latest git commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47UZk.png)

[pic of heroku deploy message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB5tq.png)

UPDATE: So I made minor changes to test and they do in fact get updated. I did a console.log and realized the response[0] variable prints as undefined from the heroku logs but it prints just fine locally. I have no idea what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I actually solved the issue. Turns out I needed to edit my `.insert(note)` call to look like this `.insert(note, ['id'])` and then send the json as `{id: response[0].id, message: ''}`. Locally response was returning the id and on heroku it was returning something totally different. I also realized that the local database I was using was sqlite3 and heroku is using postgres. I'm guessing the returned response variable is different when using one or the other.

Answer (score -1):

Not solving your problem but might help to debug:
You can install the heroku CLI: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli and login into the server with `heroku run bash -a <appname>`. You could check if the right code is uploaded, your node version, and the version of the node_modules in question.

Comment: I believe this should have been a comment. Look it even fits nicely: "You can install the heroku CLI: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli and login into the server with heroku run bash -a <appname>. You could check if the right code is uploaded, your node version, and the version of the node_modules in question"